# While working with survey data, How can I combine column in pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a survey and I want to create a row that combine all the result?

```
survey = pd.DataFrame({
'username':['Mat', 'Ryan', 'Judith', 'John'],  
'choice [Website]':['Yes', 'No', 'No', 'No'] , 
'choice [Friend]':['No', 'Yes', 'No', 'No'] , 
'choice [Poster]':['No', 'No', 'Yes', 'No'] , 
'choice [Other]':['No', 'No', 'No', 'Yes'],
})
survey
```

[image: enter code here]

Expected Result (adding another column)
[image]

[image]

```
def how_this_you_find_about_us(patron_answer):
    """

    Keyword arguments: 
    patron_answer-> string : A pandas row

    Return:
    answer -> : Answer type
    """
    if patron_answer['choice [Website]'] == 'Yes':
        return 'Website'
    elif patron_answer['choice [Friend]'] == 'Yes':
        return "Friend"
    elif patron_answer['choice [Poster]'] == 'Yes':
        return "Poster"
    else:
        return "Other"
```

applying the function

```
survey['answer?'] = survey.apply(lambda x: how_this_you_find_about_us(x))
```

I have an error while trying to apply the function

```
KeyError: ('choice [Website]', 'occurred at index Response ID')
```

type

```
survey.dtypes
username            object
choice [Website]    object
choice [Friend]     object
choice [Poster]     object
choice [Other]      object
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything works fine, except for one little thing: `DataFrame.apply`, by default, applies the function to each column.

To fix, add `axis=1` to the function call. Then, it will apply the function to each row ([relevant docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)).

```
survey['answer?'] = survey.apply(lambda x: how_this_you_find_about_us(x), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a easier way of doing so, but I could resolve your problem transforming the values in Boolean, finding the idxmax and concating back

```
survey=survey.replace('No', False).replace('Yes', True)
temp=survey.drop('username',axis=1).idxmax(axis=1).reset_index()
pd.concat([survey,temp], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `filter` , select the value you need , then `dot` with bool, then `str.extract`

```
s=survey.filter(like='choice')
survey['New']=s.eq('Yes').dot(s.columns).str.extract('\[(\w+)\]',expand=False)
survey
  choice [Friend] choice [Other] choice [Poster] choice [Website] username  \
0              No             No              No              Yes      Mat   
1             Yes             No              No               No     Ryan   
2              No             No             Yes               No   Judith   
3              No            Yes              No               No     John   
       New  
0  Website  
1   Friend  
2   Poster  
3    Other
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another way using numpy:

```
answer_ixs = np.argwhere(survey.values=='Yes').T[1]
survey['answer?'] = survey.columns[answer_ixs].str.extract('\[(\w+)\]')
```